# How to write arm assembly on the Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: assembly, arm, raspberry-pi4

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B. I've got Raspbian working on it and such. Now I want to write some ARM assembly onto a new SD card to blink an LED connected to one of the GPIO pins.

I am fine with the code but I am struggling with the rest.

I have been following this tutorial (based on RPi3)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jN7Fm_4ovio&t=10s&ab_channel=LowLevelLearning

I am struggling to compile the code I have written in Assembly as I  do not really understand the process. Could someone explain how I can install the correct ARM compiler on my Linux virtual machine and then use it to compile my .s code file?

Comment: this is not necessarily a stackoverflow question.  perhaps... But for this specific topic go to the https://forums.raspberrypi.com page, then baremetal and assembly.  There are many pinned examples and sources for tools etc.  Plus a wealth of information and people on that forum that know this information in detail about the chip/board as well as the elementary installing of toolchains.

Comment: if ubuntu/mint you can just apt get binutils-arm-none-eabi or binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi.  If you have more than one pi then you can run a 32 bit linux on it and then get native gnu tools for that (apt-get build-essential, or whatever depending on the distro).  Understand that arm32 bit (classic, aarch32) and arm64 bit (aarch64) are completely incompatible instruction sets and as far as gnu is concerned they are different builds of the toolchain (cant build for 32 bit arm with a 64 bit arm toolchain)

Comment: you dont compile assembly you assemble it.   in the gnu world the assembler and linker and other tools fall under the binutils project/package (gcc would be the compiler but you dont need it yet).  now you probably want to still search for terms like gnu cross compiler for arm on linux and then once you find that look for binutils.  searching for cross assembler might not help as much.   there are many pre-builts and building your own assembler/linker/etc from binutils sources is pretty easy and many sites explaining that

Comment: @old_timer thanks for run down. Could you clarify1 more thing? The R Pi4 is 64-bit right so I can only use the 64-bit tool chain?

Comment: not true, the processor can be run in 32 bit armv7-a compatibility mode or in the armv8-a aarch64 bit mode.   the way the raspi folks have done it is that there are different kernel.img filenames and which file name you name your file on the sd card can determine which mode they boot the processor in

Comment: so you can use a 64 bit example or a 32 bit.  there is also something that the pi folks do is let you boot like a linux image and what I mean by that is they put the actual boot code at address zero that "sorts the cores" as I call it . .their hardware choses to release reset on all the cores at once (not how all chip vendors do it) so all the cores boot at the same time fetching the same instructions, so you need code up front that

Comment: looks at the id for the core, their code (also published on the pi forums), does this and only core 0 then goes on to execute the code at the linux kernel entry point address (which varies and you control by filename basically 0x8000 or 0x80000)

Comment: you mess with this booting mode with I think it is config.txt or some txt file on the sd card, you do not want to be doing this at this entry level.   load into the 0x8000 or 0x80000 address and only have to deal with core 0.

Comment: there is also multiple modes for the 64 bit and for get the term execution levels, one is hyp and then the other is the traditional svc or supervisor mode.  now this is chosen by that boot code at address zero so if you do not take over that code, then you get what you get when loading normally as if you were a linux kernel

Comment: lots of ciscussions in those forums about the execution levels, changing levels, how to boot the thing.   honestly an old arm11 based pi-zero is the easiest starting point.

Comment: but with a tiny bit learning and work 32 or 64 bit mode the pi4 can blink an led too

Comment: Main question: do you want to do bare metal development (i.e. write your own OS) or just write Linux programs for the RPi in assembly?  Even if your end goal is the former, it'll be a lot easier to start with the latter.  You can do GPIO from a Linux program just fine.

Comment: @old_timer thanks for the time and all the info, very helpful!

Comment: @fuz I want do bare metal development, I am quite comfortable with reading the processor datasheets and controlling gpio through their respective registers. I am just very inexperienced with getting the system set up and ready.

Comment: I recommend just do bare metal not linux, the pi is a somewhat nice-ish platform for this, very hard to brick, good community, etc.  Lacking on the documentation, but there are other things that compensate for that...

Comment: https://azeria-labs.com/writing-arm-assembly-part-1/ and https://www.bit138.com/how-to-write-assembly-instructions-for-programming-a-32-bit-arm-core-with-a-raspberry-pi.html